# Yesod generateFormPost - No instance for (RenderMessage master0 FormMessage)

Tags: haskell, yesod

I tried to follow this screencast by Michael Snoyman http://vimeo.com/39646807. However, it seems changes to the i18n causes that code to fail. I can't find any information on how to solve this problem on a scaffolded site and I can't quite make sense of the information given here http://www.yesodweb.com/book/internationalization.

This is the error i get, referring to code in Home.hs:

```
No instance for (RenderMessage master0 FormMessage)
  arising from a use of `generateFormPost'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (RenderMessage master0 FormMessage)
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  (formWidget, enctype) <- generateFormPost noteForm
In the expression:
  do { (formWidget, enctype) <- generateFormPost noteForm;
       defaultLayout ($(widgetFile "notes")) }
In an equation for `getNotesR':
    getNotesR
      = do { (formWidget, enctype) <- generateFormPost noteForm;
             defaultLayout ($(widgetFile "notes")) }
```

The information seems pretty clear, the problem is I can't figure out how to add an instance declaration for (RenderMessage master0 FormMessage).

Here's the code I added to Home.hs

```
noteForm = renderBootstrap $ Note
    <$> areq textField "Title" Nothing
    <*> areq textField "Content" Nothing

getNotesR = do
    (formWidget, enctype) <- generateFormPost noteForm
    defaultLayout $(widgetFile "notes")

postNotesR = return ()
getNoteR noteId = return ()
```

Ant the following is from templates/notes.hamlet

```
<form method=post enctype=#{enctype}>
    ^{formWidget}
    <input type=submit>
```

Comment: What happens if you add a type signature `noteForm :: Form Note`?

Comment: Yes, adding the type signature did it. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general proposition, when you see something like this:

```
No instance for (RenderMessage master0 FormMessage)
```

Bear in mind that `master0` (or anything like it starting with a lowercase letter) is a *free type variable* that has not been instantiated to a concrete type. You can mentally replace it with `a` if that helps. So now we see that the message says there's no *generic* `RenderMessage` instance that is uniquely determined by `FormMessage` in the second parameter and an *arbitrary* type in the first parameter.

therefore, the usual way to fix this is to figure out what you want to instantiate the free type to, and to provide a type signature or other hint to fix it to that instantiation.

In this case, the type signature suggested by Michael Snoyman `noteForm :: Form Note` serves this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding this code ?

```
instance RenderMessage [The name of your Yesod instance] FormMessage where
    renderMessage _ _ = defaultFormMessage
```

See http://www.yesodweb.com/book/internationalization.

Comment: I tried adding that to Home.hs and got the following error:

`Duplicate instance declarations:
      instance RenderMessage App FormMessage
        -- Defined at Handler\Home.hs:59:10
      instance RenderMessage App FormMessage -- Defined in \`Foundation'`.
Turns out Foundation.hs contains the exact same code